# How to enable AmazonS3 static website hosting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My problems are that S3 Properties Tab shows
[image]

When I click use this and then save, button is not active any more.It changes color and I can not do anything about it.

This is the content of my S3
[image]

My S3 policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1575283327440",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1575283033809",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::gitlab-jekyll-*********/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1575283267330",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::5771********:user/terraformadminuser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::gitlab-jekyll-**********/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to fix this? I can not show my bucket id because it has public access.

[image]

Comment: It might be the case that the button is enabled only when the index.html file is already present. Can you confirm this?

Comment: It is present,I will add picture.

Comment: I copied from my gitlab to s3 with aws cp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type index.html to both input boxs, then  you can save

Comment: Only *Index document* is required.  Don't put that value in *error document* unless it is actually appropriate for your use case.